# Export Installed Software into Excel Sheet

Tags: csv, batch-file, export-to-csv

I'm struggling to make a batch script that writes all installed software (using wmic) into a csv sheet. The Issue is that all the Data is written into a single Row of the CSV, which I can't seperate from each other. My Idea is the following:

```bsh
powershell.exe -command "& {wmic product get vendor,name,version >'\\Server\Location\%COMPUTERNAME%.csv ' }"
```

Does anybody know how to seperate the Data into single Rows (namely vendor|name|version)?

Greetings!

Comment: You don't need `Powershell`. `wmic` runs fine in `cmd`. Use the `/format` switch to chose the desired format: `wmic product get vendor,name,version /format:csv`

Comment: In addition to what @Stephan said, powershell has awesome wmi internal support via `Get-WmiObject`.  If all you want is what you are asking for, I would stick with WMIC/CMD for now.. but if you want to do more complicated things with the data returned, then powershell is a better place to be.  Also, *eventually*.. Microsoft will stop supporting the WMIC tool in favor of PowerShell.